# How can I view an HTML that I have written in Python?

Tags: python, html

I am currently learning HTML in my Python class. My assignment is to ask the user for their name and a short bio of themselves and print it on a web-page.

I believe my code is correct, I'm not too confused on that, but after I've created everything how do I see if it actually worked? When I try to open the file location with google chrome nothing happens.

```
def main():
    f = open('Userbio', 'w')
    f.write("<html>" + "\n")
    f.write("<heads>" + "\n")


    name = input("What is your name?")
    bio = input ("Please write a sentence about yourself!")

    f.write("<naming>" + "\n")
    f.write(name)
    f.write("/naming>" + "\n")

    fout.write("</heads>" + "\n")
    fout.write("</body>" + "\n")
    fout.write("</html>" + "\n")
    fout.close()

    f.close()
main()
```

Basically after this program is written and the user inputs their information I'm trying to figure out how to open the web page.

This method works when I use a regular writer like notepad, I just save it and open it with chrome and I can see my webpage. But not Python?

Answer (score 3):

Change `f = open('Userbio', 'w')` to `f = open('Userbio.html', 'w')`.

You need to rename `<heads>` to `<head>` and add the `<body>` tag.

You will also need to move the `<naming>` tag out of the `<head>` and into the `<body>` tag in order to see any text inside of the naming tag.

As python does not have a built in web browser, you will be able to open the .html file with a browser like Chrome.

If you want to be able to parse and manipulate the html before writing to file, there are several libraries, like BeautifulSoup, that can do that for you.

Comment: Thank-you! I had just realized I didn't close everything!                     Even after I finish all this though, how do I actually open the html? Like using google chrome or firefox for example? To view the output?

Comment: Thank you so much!